# React material ui responsive drawer - I want to remove the padding from the Toolbar

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Let's say I have the code from here:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-nqkupy?file=demo.tsx

which is the code from the material ui docs, "Responsive drawer" section:

https://mui.com/material-ui/react-drawer/#responsive-drawer

but I added an image as a logo at the top of the menu.

How can I remove the space above the logo?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `<Toolbar />` if you don't use it. Or move the logo above `<Toolbar />`.

[image]

Comment: Removing Toolbar fixed it. Thanks. What does it do though?

Comment: If you need to use the `Toolbar` just place the logo as child of it like `<Toolbar>...logo...</Toolbar>`

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following :

```css
img {
    position: relative;
    left: 3.5em;
    bottom: 1em;
}

/** Also Use a Class Selector if you don't want to alter all <img> elements on page.**/
```

Add this to your CSS File. This should work although you might need to play around with some media queries in order to make it responsive.

[It also centers the logo, looks better IMO.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iBeb3.png)